# Path Optimizer system data (SFMC)

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-views, path-optimizer

Is it possible to retrieve Path Optimizer data from the data views or from tracking extract?
We export both sets daily to BiqQuery.

Example:
A/B test, 2 versions (10k vs 10k)
Winning (50k) version send automatically after 1 day

Is it possible to query the results of the A/B test (10k vs 10k) from Data Views of Tracking Extract?

When looking at the data, the mails are send via one sendID. Both the test send(10k) as the winning version (50k). So the sendid has a send count of 60k.

I'm looking for a more easy way then using the eventdate to split. Because it will be a lot of work to lookup all dates every time. For example when using Path optimizer in triggered journeys.

So is there some kind of indicator to distinguish the A/B 'test' send from the winning version?